# C++ VS17 gives different output than same code in Linux Subsystem

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio, g++, mingw

I was having trouble finding an answer for this. I'm hoping it's not a duplicate. I wrote code for a leetcode.com challenge which works in VS17 as expected but not on leetcode or on my Ubuntu WSL compiled with g++. The code searches for the longest substring with unique letters. The answer for string "pwwkew" is 3 (VS17 gets 3), but on Linux and on leetcode is spits out 4. I'm guessing it has to do with MinGW vs G++.  On Ubuntu I compiled the program with several different versions of C++ using: `g++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror string.cpp -std=c++1y -o string`

Thanks in advance! Also this is my first post so go easy on me :).

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <unordered_set>
using namespace std;


/*
Input: "abcabcbb"
Output: 3
Explanation: The answer is "abc", with the length of 3.
*/

int main()
{
    string s = "pwwkew";

    //this algorithm adds unique chars to a set in the order that they appear in the string
    //after each for loop, the maximum number between maxLen and the size of the set is recorded
    //when a duplicate letter is found, all of the letters up until and including the last
    //occurence of that letter are erased, so the remaining letters are only the uniques in the current 'substring'
    unordered_set<char> seen;
    int maxLen = 0;
    for (int end = 0; end < s.size(); end++)
    {       
        if (seen.insert(s[end]).second == false)
        {
            if (seen.begin() == seen.find(s[end]))
            {
                seen.erase(seen.begin());
            }
            else {
                seen.erase(seen.begin(), seen.find(s[end+1]));
            }
            seen.insert(s[end]);
        }
        maxLen = max(maxLen, (int)seen.size());
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Edit:  I added an iterator loop to print the values in the set after each initial for loop execution, and VS17 prints:

```
p
p w
w
w k
w k e
k e w
```

While Linux prints:

```
p
w p
w p
k p w
e k p w
w
```

So I'm guessing the insert order is reversed by one compiler which would cause my set.erase to execute in the wrong order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are assuming the ordering of values in the unordered_set. Remember that the order can be dependent on implementation and you can have different behavior with different implementations.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So even if they’re showed in the same order every time in the debugger and in print statements, they might not be in that order when being found and deleted?

Comment: You should never ever consider anything in the set apart from contents. So, Order is a definite NO. May be you can use a vector/list for correctness and i guess set+vector or set+stack for an optimal solution. Or may be you can write your own implementation

Answer (score 0):

An `unordered_set` stores its elements in nondeterministic order.  Trying to delete the first 2 elements you added to the set with `seen.erase` and two iterators will not work.

Rethink what you're doing and pick a different container.

Comment: Thanks! I’ll see if I can swing the logic with an ordered set.